# How to get a running total for a column in a csv file while depending on a unique variable in a different column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, cumulative-sum

```
import csv
def getDataFromFile(filename, dataList):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    csvReader = csv.reader(file)
    for aList in csvReader:
        dataList.append(aList)
    file.close()

def getTotalByYear(expendDataList):
    total = 0
    for row in expendDataList:
        expenCount = float(row[2])
        total += expenCount**

Rtotal = input(print("Enter 'every' or a particular year. "))
if Rtotal == 'every' or == 'Every':
    print(expenCount)
```

As you can see I got the running total for column 2 if you type `every` or `Every` but I don't understand how to do a running total for column 2 while dependent on a certain variable in column one.

In this case my CSV file has three columns of data. A `year` field, an `item` field, and an `expenditure` field. How do I get a running total of the `expenditure` field based on a certain year?

```
expendDataList = [] 
fname = "expenditures.csv"
getDataFromFile(fname, expendDataList)
getTotalByYear(expendDataList)
```

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with your question, but `if Rtotal == 'every' or 'Every'` does not do what you think it does. Use e.g. `if Rtotal == 'every' or Rtotal == 'Every'` instead.

Comment: mkrieger1 thanks for catching that I am still new to python but I am striving to be a better coder.

Answer (score 0):

Producing a running total is good task for a generator function. This example uses the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function to filter out unwanted years (a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)/ [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) could be used instead).  Then it iterates over the selected rows to produce the results.

```
import csv 


def running_totals(year):
    with open('year-item-expenditure.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        predicate = None if year.lower() == 'every' else lambda row: row['Year'] == year
        total = 0 
        for row in filter(predicate, reader):
            total += float(row['Expenditure'])
            yield total


totals = running_totals('2019')
for total in totals:
    print(total)
```

Another approach would be to use [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), though you still have to perform all of the filtering, so there's not much benefit to doing this unless you need performance.

```
import csv
import itertools


def running_totals(year):
    with open('year-item-expenditure.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        predicate = None if year.lower() == 'every' else lambda row: row['Year'] == year
        # Create a generator expression that yields expenditures as floats
        expenditures = (float(row['Expenditure']) for row in filter(predicate, reader))
        for total in itertools.accumulate(expenditures):
            yield total
```